# Yammer - Is it possible to get access token by registered app?

Tags: yammer

GET https://www.yammer.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=[:client_id]&redirect_uri=[:redirect_uri]&response_type=token

Above request returns access token but I don't know how does it expire so I want to have a "**refreshing**" method when user is not logged on.

GET oauth2/authorize?client_id=[:client_id]&response_type=code&redirect_uri=[:redirect_uri]

POST oauth2/access_token
client_id=[:client_id]&client_secret=[:client_secret]&code=[:code]&grant_type=authorization_code

It requires user already logged into Yammer.

Is there a way to get access token (**user is not logged in**) by registered app (client_id & client_secret) or something like that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get access token (**user is not logged in**)...

A user must be logged-in to able to generate an access token.

You'd be happy to know that tokens generated this way are long lived. They hardly expire unless the user revokes the app's access, or the app and/or the owner is disabled/deleted. So you really do not need a refresher token service. Once you obtain the token, you may want to save it a safe location/DB and re-use it for as many times as you like. Although it's a good practice to  refresh tokens at regular intervals.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know exactly how long it will be expired?

Comment: As I mentioned, it is "long lived". Those are the words the Yammer folks like using - "long lived", but I honestly think it stays active unless an action is performed to invalidate it.